# How to create schema in MongoDB using python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, schema

I'm fairly new to MongoDB. I'll try my best to summarize the problem at hand here. I've been provided three different JSON schemas and i want to create this schemas in MongoDB using python. My code is as follows:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/")

mydb=client['UserDetails']

information = mydb.Userinformation

user_schema = {

    'firstName': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'required': True,
        'coerce': str.capitalize
    },
    'lastName': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'required': True,
        'coerce': str.capitalize
    },
    'email': {
        'type': 'string',
        "required": False,
        "coerce": str,
        "nullable": True
    },
    'phoneNo': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True
    },
    'userId': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True
    },
    'patientId': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True
    },
    'age': {
        'type': 'integer'
    },
    "userStatus": {
        "type": "integer",
        "nullable": True
    }
}

information.insert_many(user_schema)
```

The above code line gives me an error as below

TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

information.insert_one(user_schema)

And trying this gives me an error

cannot encode object: method 'capitalize' of 'str' objects, of type: class 'method_descriptor'

Any help how to create this schema in mongoDB using python will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting this to be the databases schema? Or do you just want to insert that data into a collection?

Comment: Yes i want it to be a databases schema. But i guess what i'm trying to do here is insert in into a collection. Would it not work by simple inserting  ? If not could you please guide to make a databases schema.

Comment: `str.capitalize` is a function which cannot be encoded and stored in the database. This is why you get the BSON error. That value needs to a valid python data type.

Comment: Have you tried `mongoengine`? See guide here https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/#working-with-collections-and-documents_1

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB uses a [JSON schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) of BSON types; your schema doesn't match the spec.

There's no concept of "coerce" and uniqueness is handled through [unique indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/).

I've got you started with this code snippet that gets you some of the way there, but this is a lot of your own research you will need to do.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import CollectionInvalid
from collections import OrderedDict

db = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27019/")['mydatabase']

user_schema = {
    'firstName': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'required': True,
    },
    'lastName': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'required': True,
    },
    'email': {
        'type': 'string',
        "required": False,
    },
    'phoneNo': {
        'type': 'int',
        'required': True,
    },
    'userId': {
        'type': 'int',
        'required': True,
    },
    'patientId': {
        'type': 'int',
        'required': True,
    },
    'age': {
        'type': 'int'
    },
    "userStatus": {
        "type": "int"
    }
}

collection = 'Userinformation'
validator = {'$jsonSchema': {'bsonType': 'object', 'properties': {}}}
required = []

for field_key in user_schema:
    field = user_schema[field_key]
    properties = {'bsonType': field['type']}
    minimum = field.get('minlength')

    if type(minimum) == int:
        properties['minimum'] = minimum

    if field.get('required') is True: required.append(field_key)

    validator['$jsonSchema']['properties'][field_key] = properties

if len(required) > 0:
    validator['$jsonSchema']['required'] = required

query = [('collMod', collection),
         ('validator', validator)]

try:
    db.create_collection(collection)
except CollectionInvalid:
    pass

command_result = db.command(OrderedDict(query))
```